# Al tener un carrito armado, quiero mandar un mensaje por whatsapp con los productos seleccionados. Como hago?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whatsapp

export const ViewItem = ({  nombre, img, descrip }) => {

```
const handleWsp = () => {

    window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=1568501644&text=Hola%21+Quiero'+{nombre}+'+comunicarme+con+ustedes&type=phone_number&app_absent=0', '_blank')
}
```

Comment: Si tu propósito es que el mensaje se envíe automáticamente sin intervención del usuario, sin abrir un link o entrar directamente a WhatsApp, no es posible de manera oficial, pero aún puedes usar APIs de terceros como Vonage o Twilio para enviar mensajes de forma automática. Sin embargo, si tu propósito no es ese, puedes usar la API de WhatsApp, la cual va a requerir que el usuario entre directamente a WhatsApp y envíe el mensaje por su cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no soy un experto en react.js, pero asumiendo la similitud con javascript, hay un problema en la forma en que estás pasando la variable nombre en la URL de WhatsApp. Para concatenar la variable correctamente en la cadena de texto, debes utilizar el operador `+` en lugar de `{nombre}`. yo lo haria de la siguiente forma:

```
export const ViewItem = ({ nombre, img, descrip }) => {
    const handleWsp = () => {
        const mensaje = `Hola! Quiero ${nombre} comunicarme con ustedes`;
        const url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=1568501644&text=${encodeURIComponent(mensaje)}&type=phone_number&app_absent=0`;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
}
```

he creado la variable mensaje que contiene el texto que se enviará a través de WhatsApp. Luego, utilizamos la función `encodeURIComponent()` para codificar correctamente el texto del mensaje en la URL de WhatsApp. Finalmente, construimos la URL completa con la variable url y abrimos una nueva ventana/tabla utilizando `window.open()`.

Yo he utilizado algo similar para validaciones de sesiones y como factor secundario de autenticacion...

Comment: En realidad, `window.open()` está disponible en React, siempre y cuando sea desde el navegador, en entornos como React Native, se necesita un enfoque más avanzado, como un elemento `WebView`.

Comment: pero el usuario uso la etiqueta reactjs.